# Is it true that Sri Krishna's flute is still hidden somewhere in India?

Tags: mahabharata, krishna

After the death of Sri Krishna, what happened to his belongings? I heard somewhere that his flute is still hidden in some secret place in India. 
Is there any scriptural evidence to prove that his belongings other than his heart are hidden somewhere in India.

Comment: If it it *hidden* in a **secret** place I doubt anyone here would know. :)

Comment: @surya true :) hope someone might've heard about it

Comment: @sss The question is not about the flute. The question is about Krishna himself. Because is a fiction from Hindu tradition.

Comment: @JoWehler i think this is just your opinion. But on contrary, Many Hindus believe Sri Krishna as pure Consciousness who manifested on Earth as Avatar to establish Dharma some 5000 Years ago. So, there's no second question of considering Him as fiction here by users or by OP.

Comment: Even I have heard about this long ago, but I don't remember :-(  I was trying to find but couldn't. And I think it's really important to know.

Comment: @The Destroyer I know about the importance of Krishna for Hindu belief. My commrnt wants to emphasize that it is much more difficult - not to say impossible - to validate that Krishna existed than to find a certain flute.

Comment: @JoWegler i agree with you and I fear that this question may never get answer. But there are certainly many proofs for existence of Krishna and Mahabharata. But finding Flute may be difficult. I will provide evidence for supporting Mahabharata shortly from research done by Archeological Survey of India.

Comment: Way to guys. Everything what have been told in Hindu Vedic Scriptures is true. Lord Krishna's elder brother Balaraama's wife Revathi is some thousands of years older than him. She is the first time traveller in entire human race. So definitely we'll one day find the flute and other proofs.

Comment: @jowehler That is only because, to the westerner, "history"  as is defined by the western sciences starts only about 3000 years ago. That is not an accurate measuring rod for claiming that Krishna is merely  belief or fiction. Western education falls painfully short in many aspects. One must be cognizant of this before making assertions about concepts and entities much older than the civilization or history or education one is familiar with.

Comment: Sss - it is said that there is a vamsi vata in Vrindavana that still resonates Krishna's music. This is corroborated by our own contemporaries. Secondly, as you advance in yoga, one of the 10 nada's the yogi hears is the sound of a flute. This has been theorized as the flute sound heard by Gopis. So we may surmise that Krishna's flute is hidden in yogic planes.

Comment: @moonstar2001 I admire Hinduism for its fanciful fictions in art and literature. But I do not mix up fantasy with reality, neither old texts with historical investigations.

Comment: @JoWehler Reality and historical investigations as defined by western education. That's my point. Western education is not all that. It certainly does not give the West the intellectual or moral authority to say Hindu literature is fanciful and fictitious. We certainly have very advanced literary works of fiction but what you think are works of fiction are not fiction and I don't think you will ever understand this. Therefore, such opinions based on limited knowledge are not useful in any manner.

Comment: @JoWehler FYI, Hinduism acknowledges three forms of exploration of knowledge - mantra, tantra and yantra. Western education is only familiar with one form, viz, yantra. So an inferior system (with only 1 form of exploration) making over-arching judgements about a superior system (with multiple paths) is naive at best.

Comment: @moonstar2001 i agree with you. Our education system has been destroyed by foreign invaders since thousands of years. They took our knowledge to their countries and spread out as theirs.

Comment: @sss I assume the background of your statement conforms with  Malhotra's position, e,g, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rz01RAOMxFc

Comment: @sss - The question appears irrelevant because, why would you want to find the flute of Lord Krishna. Nowadays, it has become a fashion after a few western excavations and movies showing some strange explorations. Now people are after Lord's Flute etc. Westerners are smart. They made sure we all use BC ( before Christ) and A.D   thereby giving credence to existence of Christ, whereas in reality there is no proof that Christ existed. At the same time, we can't make a sweeping statement  that all western education is bad.